# parsing multiple child with sax parser in Android

Tags: android, xml, sax

I can parse xml file with sax parser, but when I need to add child attribute under a attribute then how I can get the value? my xml file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<marketlist>
  <market>
      <name restricted="yes">boss</name>
      <motorway>M6</motorway>
      <junction>J3</junction>
      <petrol_hour>
          <mon>7am - 8pm</mon>
          <tues>7am - 8pm</tues>

      </petrol_hour>
</market>
```

I want to parse and get mon and tues values. Any suggesstion? My android code for parsing is here:

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        elementOn = false;

        /** 
         * Sets the values after retrieving the values from the XML tags
         * */ 
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
            data.setMarketName(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("motorway"))
            data.setMotorway(elementValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("junction"))
            data.setJunction(elementValue);
```